# Removing specific Element from an Array using findIndex() - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this function that needs to delete an item thats clicked from the array. Im sure its a simple fix but its not deleting it from the array. I think its something to do with how Im executing the function in the button? IM not entirely sure.
error: **TypeError: e.findIndex is not a function**

```js
const deleteClaim = (claim,value) => {
  const index = claim.findIndex(element => element === value); // 1
  const result = claim.splice(index, 1);
  return result

}
```

the button is

```js
      <button onClick={(e) => deleteClaim(claim, e.target.value)} >X </button>
```

Comment: Does button even have a value attribute in your code?

Comment: TypeError: e.findIndex is not a function

Comment: 'Result' is probably the correct answer. However, do you assign it back to the list?

Comment: what do you mean Result is the best answer?

Comment: If this is react, you need to set the state with the updated array.

Answer (score -1):

This is a small piece of code of my working project

> **selectedForDeleteArr** is the array

```
function removeStatusEnum(id) {
if (selectedForDeleteArr.includes(id)) {
    let index = selectedForDeleteArr.indexOf(id)
    if (index > -1) {
        selectedForDeleteArr.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $("#sts_id" + id).removeClass("selected-to-delete")
} else {
    selectedForDeleteArr.push(id)
    $("#sts_id" + id).addClass("selected-to-delete")
}
console.log(selectedForDeleteArr)
```

}